# Extracting specific data from list format data extracted from dictionary format read from Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, nested

I am pulling specific data from data in nested dictionary format.
As a result of selecting specific data as the first step in the dictionary format, the following list format data was obtained. The data type of each row is a list.

```
dataset 

0                                                      []
1                                                      []
2                                                      []
3                [{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 'information1'}]
4       [{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 'information2'}, {'...

type(dataset[0])
=> list
type(dataset)
=> pandas.core.series.Series
```

I am trying to extract specific data ('C') from here again.
When using the following code for each row, I can successfully pull specific data.

```
[d['C'] for d in dict_test2[1]]
=> ['information1']
```

However, since the data is over 40k, if I create and execute the following method, I see an error message.

```
def get_c(d):
    return [d['C'] for d in dataset]
dataset2 = dataset.apply(get_c)

=> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your df.dtypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the column values are python list, you can explode the column, and get the dictionary values using `Series.str['key']` then `dropna` and finally call `tolist()` to get the values as list:

```py
>>> df[0].explode().str['C'].dropna().to_list()

['information1', 'information2']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When running your code, I received the following error message.
```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'explode'```

Comment: @SEan1820 It means that the data you have mentioned is a list but not a pandas dataframe, you need to have dataframe and `0` in the solution is the column name for the column with list of dictionary vlaues. Try passing the data to `pd.DataFrame` and create a dataframe out of the values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your second reply. 
I ran the code after converting the format as advised. But I see another error message.

```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
.......

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)```

Comment: @SEan1820 Can you add a sample from list to the question that you are passing to DataFrame?

Comment: The raw data is large, so the example above is the best example I can show you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how you are reading the data?